# Placing a chest so it faces a specific direction

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I place this chest in a 180 degree angle on the Y axis?

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~2 
{
    Block:"minecraft:chest",Time:1,TileEntityData:
    {
        Items:[
        {
            id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:4,Slot:11,Count:1,tag:
            {
                CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]
            }
        },
        {
            id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:3,Slot:13,Count:1,tag:
            {
                CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]
            }
        },
        {
            id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:1,Slot:15,Count:1,tag:
            {
                CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]
            }
        }
    ]}
}
```

I tired changing it like how I do with other blocks, but it did not work.

Comment: With the `/setblock` command, the chest will face away from whatever block is next to it. Hopefully you can make it work in that way. I am doing some more research for you now.

Comment: [This](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-31365) could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Data` tag for FallingSand states the Damage value of the block, and in the case of chests, determines the directional facing. You can find various values for chest facing [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chest#Block_data).

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~2 {Block:"minecraft:chest",Data:3,Time:1,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:4,Slot:11,Count:1,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]}},{id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:3,Slot:13,Count:1,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]}},{id:"minecraft:stained_glass",Damage:1,Slot:15,Count:1,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:iron_block"]}}]}}
```